# How to find all systems of distinct representatives using i.e. Hopcroft–Karp algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I would like to find all [systems of distinct representatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversal_(combinatorics)) in bipartite graph. I've found Hopcroft–Karp algorithm, which finds maximal matching, which I would like to implement. But I don't know how should I modify it to find ALL transversals.

Or maybe, someone knows any other solution to solve this problem, it doesn't need to be very quick algorithm.

Could somebody give me some tips? Thank you in advance

Comment: You should give a description of your problem. What is a system of distinct representatives?

Comment: So it sounds like you want to list all (maximal?) matchings of a bipartite graph. There's a paper here for perfect matchings : http://research.nii.ac.jp/~uno/papers/isaac01.pdf if that's helpful